# What happens if a post is deleted after you've completed 500 total non-self edits?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

So lets say you have 550 non-self edits.

One of those posts got deleted just right now. I would lose 2 reputation since that post I gained some reputation from it

Would 2 reputation get passed onto another edit where I didn't get reputation (501st+ edit)? Or do I have to make a new edit to get 2 points back?

Comment: @Servy only suggested edits will gain rep? Saw you editing out a tag

Comment: That is correct, non-suggested edits earn no reputation.

Comment: @Servy Just curious if you have the full editing rights (2k+ rep) you can't suggest edits no more?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Except on tag wikis.